# JavaFX Error while navigating from 1 page to another

Tags: javafx

**When I click on submit button on Login page homepage should be displayed but I get this error:**

**EXCEPTION**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1768)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.emo.Navigator.showLoginPage(Navigator.java:61)
    at com.emo.view.LoginController.authenticate(LoginController.java:37)
    ... 57 more
```

**MAIN APP**

```
package com.emo;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.emo.view.HomePageController;
import com.emo.view.LoginController;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Navigator nav = new Navigator();
        nav.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("EMO APP");
        nav.initRootLayout();
        nav.showLoginPage();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Login Controller**

```
 package com.emo.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import com.emo.MainApp;
import com.emo.Navigator;

public class LoginController {
    @FXML
    private TextField usernameText;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordText;
    @FXML
    private Label statusLabel;
    int attempt = 0;
    private MainApp mainApp;

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
    }

    /*
     * @FXML void nextPane() { VistaNavigator.loadVista(VistaNavigator.VISTA_2);
     * }
     */

    @FXML
    public void authenticate() {
        if (attempt < 3) {
            if (usernameText.getText().equals("abc")
                    && passwordText.getText().equals("abc")) {
                statusLabel.setText("");
                Navigator nav = new Navigator();
                nav.showLoginPage();
            } else {
                attempt++;
                statusLabel.setText("Invalid Credentials");
            }
        } else {
            statusLabel.setText("Your account has been locked");
        }

    }
}
```

**HomePage Controller**

```
    package com.emo.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import com.emo.MainApp;

public class HomePageController {
    // Reference to the main application.
    private MainApp mainApp;

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
    }

    @FXML
    public void emo() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void cashManagement() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void reports() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void userProfile() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void email() {

    }
}
```

**Navigator**

```
package com.emo;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.emo.view.HomePageController;
import com.emo.view.LoginController;

public class Navigator {

    Stage primaryStage;
    BorderPane rootLayout=null;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    AnchorPane pane = null;

    /**
     * Returns the main stage.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class
                    .getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the Login Page inside the root layout.
     */
    public void showLoginPage() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class
                    .getResource("view/eMO_SignIn.fxml"));

            pane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(pane);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            LoginController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(new MainApp());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showHomePage() {
        try {
            pane = null;
            // Load person overview.
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class
                    .getResource("view/eMO_HomePage.fxml"));
            pane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(pane);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            HomePageController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(new MainApp());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**eMO_Homepage.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="250.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.emo.view.HomePageController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="49.0" fitWidth="250.0" layoutY="-2.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../../Desktop/thCA60O0D6.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Home Page" textFill="#a12121">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="354.0" fitWidth="250.0" layoutY="46.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../../Desktop/thCA7ZWC4O.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button layoutX="117.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sync" />
      <VBox layoutX="2.0" layoutY="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
         <children>
            <Button id="emo" layoutY="-1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#emo" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="256.0" text="EMO">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button id="cashManagement" layoutY="56.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cashManagement" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="256.0" text="Cash Management">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button id="reports" layoutY="113.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#reports" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="256.0" text="Reports">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button id="userProfile" layoutY="170.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#userProfile" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="256.0" text="User Profile">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button id="email" layoutY="227.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#email" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="256.0" text="Email">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**eMO_SignIn.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="250.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.emo.view.LoginController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="49.0" fitWidth="250.0" layoutY="-2.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../Images/Grey.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Sign In" textFill="#a12121">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="354.0" fitWidth="250.0" layoutY="46.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../Images/Red.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <VBox layoutX="27.0" layoutY="79.0" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="79.0" text="Username:-*" textFill="#f8e4e4">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="usernameText" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="105.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="148.0" text="Password:-*" textFill="#f8e4e4">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <PasswordField fx:id="passwordText" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="174.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <Button layoutX="125.0" layoutY="236.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#authenticate" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="Sign In" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="82.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Label fx:id="statusLabel" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="46.0" layoutY="294.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="164.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="280.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**RootLayout.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `LoginController.authenticate()`, you do:

```
Navigator nav = new Navigator();
nav.showLoginPage();
```

and in `Navigator.showLoginPage()` you have:

```
pane = loader.load();
rootLayout.setCenter(pane);
```

However, at no point was `rootLayout` initialized for this `Navigator` instance, so you get the `NullPointerException` as shown in the stack trace.

One possible fix would be to give the `LoginController` a reference to the `Navigator` you have already created (and properly initialized), so it doesn't have to create a new one:

```
public class LoginController {

    private Navigator navigator ;

    public void setNavigator(navigator) {
        this.navigator = navigator ;
    }

   // everything else as before...

    @FXML
    public void authenticate() {
        if (attempt < 3) {
            if (usernameText.getText().equals("abc")
                    && passwordText.getText().equals("abc")) {
                statusLabel.setText("");
                navigator.showLoginPage();
            } else {
                attempt++;
                statusLabel.setText("Invalid Credentials");
            }
        } else {
            statusLabel.setText("Your account has been locked");
        }

    }
}
```

and then

```
public class Navigator {

    // everything else as before....

    public void showLoginPage() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class
                    .getResource("view/eMO_SignIn.fxml"));

            pane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(pane);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            LoginController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(new MainApp());

            // Give the controller access to this navigator:
            controller.setNavigator(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry actually in authenticate I calledNavigator nav = new Navigator();
nav.showHomePage(); and still I get the same exception.

Comment: Exactly. And `showLoginPage` assumes `rootLayout` has been initialized, but it hasn't.

Comment: I even tried calling Navigator.initRootLayout() again but it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: Hey even this is not working. Can you please run the code once and debug it.

Comment: There are different errors now as you are trying to reuse the same `FXMLLoader` in the navigator. Just create a new one each time.